# How do i divide buttons image equally using storyboard in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

My goal is to simply divide a button equally in a view controller, I used stack view to group them up

Example picture

[image]

and if possible I want to make the picture to be aspect fit, so that the images would look good.

The reason why the first image looks different because in the code I gave it an instruction which is

```
self.button.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
        self.button.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

What Im trying to achieve, as you can see it is fit perfectly.

[image]

Comment: you'r using autolayouts?

Comment: Have you try collection view?

Comment: @saad Im using stack view and auto layout.

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala nope, because I just want to have 3 pictures.

Comment: It looks like you want aspect fill, not aspect fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set Constraints **StackView** `CentralHorizontal`,`CentralVertical`,`EqualWidth` and `equal height` to superview.

**StackView**  alignment - Fill

**StackView**  Distribution - Fill Equal

Comment: storyboard.  add constaint to superview. no need to add constraint to button . you can see the effect from the preview.

Answer (score 1):

airsoftFreak 
You can do in following way

Take one view add three image view in it and then give the image resizing in attach image to each and every image. it will do effect as u want.

Hope you have either high resolution image or all size images in ur project so that i will not streached.

.[image]

Comment: When you talkin about high resolution, how big it should be?